# public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, authorization

Hello guys here is my problem , i create authentication on my database under role so when i put [Authorize(Roles="admin")]it will read by my program i already set it up in my web.config and also in create class but still it directing me in my log in page as default when not authorize, please help

here is my code

**MyRoleProvider.cs**

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
        {
        UserDbEntities OE = new UserDbEntities();
        string s = OE.UserAccounts.Where(x => x.Username == username).FirstOrDefault().Role;
        string[] resultS = {s};
        return resultS; 
    }
```

**Controller**

```
 public class CustomerController : Controller
    {
    private UserDbEntities db = new UserDbEntities();

    // GET: Customer
    [Authorize(Roles="admin")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Customers.ToList());
    }
```

**Web.config**

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms loginUrl="Account/Login"></forms>
        </authentication>
        <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyProvider">
          <providers>
          <clear/>
        <add name ="MyProvider" type="Sample.MyRoleProvider"/>
      </providers>   
    </roleManager>
```

Comment: Did you find solution to this issue?